# Regular expression to extract text between braces

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract text between curly braces in PHP. e.g

> Welcome {$user.first_name} to the {$site} version 1.5. Your username
>   is {$user.username}. Your reputation at present is {$user.reputation.name}

I have used `\{\$(.*?)\}` which works fine in some cases. This matches:

- {$user.first_name}
- {$site}
- {$user.username}
- {$user.reputation.name}

But now I want to match only text which has single or multiple . (dot) within the braces. i.e For the above string I should be able to match only:

- {$user.first_name}
- {$user.username}
- {$user.reputation.name}

Please help me to achieve this! Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
\{\$([^.{}]+(?:\.[^.{}]+)+)\}
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fN2yU9/1)

Note that instead of lazy dot matching `.*?`, I am using a negated character class `[^.{}]` that matches any character other than `.`, `{` or `}`. Thus, we match any block that does not contain a `.`, and is still within the braces.

The regex breakdown:

- `\{\$` - literal `{$`
- `([^.{}]+(?:\.[^.{}]+)+)` - Group 1 matching

  - `[^.{}]+` - 1 or more characters other than `.`, `{`, or `}`
  - `(?:\.[^.{}]+)+` - 1 or more (due to `+`) sequences of

    - `\.` - a literal dot
    - `[^.{}]+`  - 1 or more characters other than `.`, `{`, or `}`
- `\}` - literal `}`

[IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/NCP0U4):

```
$re = '/\{\$([^.{}]+(?:\.[^.{}]+)+)\}/'; 
$str = "Welcome {\$user.first_name} to the {\$site} version 1.5. Your username is {\$user.username}. Your reputation at present is {\$user.reputation.name}"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Comment: Great! Works like a charm. Thanks a lot for your quick reply and perfect answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

you can use this pattern:

```
~{\$([^}.]*+[^}]+)}~
```

`[^}.]*+` has a possessive quantifier and can't give characters back, so `[^}]+` can only match a dot as first character.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This expression also works for me after replacing the ~ with \. I used \{\$([^}.]*+[^}]+)\} to test your expression.

Comment: @AmitKumar: You don't need to make this replacement. You don't need to escape curly brackets too.

Comment: \{\$([^}.]*+[^}]+)\} works but ~{\$([^}.]*+[^}]+)}~ does not in my PHP test code.

Comment: @AmitKumar: https://eval.in/442275 https://regex101.com/r/lE4tP7/1 `~` are pattern delimiters (as well as `/`)

Comment: Yep that works. Sorry my fault. I was putting the expression between the / (slash) which is not required in this case. Thanks again for your time and help. Upvoted