# Regular Expression get text between braces including other braces

Tags: c#, regex

I have a "main"-string like:

```
((Gripper|Open==true OR RIT|Turning==false) AND Robot|PosX >=3 OR (Test|Close==false OR (Gripper|Open==false AND RIT|Turning==false)))
```

I want to get three sub strings in the best case:

```
1: (Gripper|Open==true OR RIT|Turning==false)
2: Robot|PosX >=3
3: (Test|Close==false OR (Gripper|Open==false AND RIT|Turning==false))
```

But only two (the one in braces [1,3]) would be fine too, since they can be replaced in the main-string, getting the 3rd[2] as a result.
Ideally with the help of regex.

All the sub strings go into a class as children so I can apply the regex for each child and get their sub strings as well.

```
1: Test|Close==false
2: (Gripper|Open==false AND RIT|Turning==false)
```

For child number three (where the first result without the braces would be optional again.

I tried something similar to [Regular expression to extract text between braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32866763/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-braces) and putting positions of the matches onto a stack, but not with the expected results.

The best regex I found so far is

```
([^()]+(?:[^()]+)+) or
([^()]+(?:)+)
```

(seriously, regex is powerful, but I have no idea what the above statements really do) which gives me

```
 1. Gripper|Open == true OR RIT|Turning==false
 2. AND Robot|PosX >=3 OR
 3. Test|Close==false OR
 4. Gripper|Open==false AND RIT|Turning==false
```

But still, 3+4 should be in only one group as

```
 Test|Close==false OR (Gripper|Open==false AND RIT|Turning==false)
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: What is the logic ? why 3 +4 should be in only one group ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for balanced parenthesis where the matches start with 2 words divided by a pipe and then an operator followed by an equals sign

In C# you might match either the [balanced parenthesis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#balancing_group_definition) or match a pattern that does not contain them using an alternation.

```
(?:\(\w+\|\w+\s*[<>!=]{1,2}[^()]*(?>[^()]+|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*(?(o)(?!)|)\)|\w+\|\w+\s*[<>!=]{1,2}\S+)
```

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\(\w+\|\w+\s*` Match `(` then 2 words divided by a pipe and 0+ whitespace chars
  - `[<>!=]{1,2}[^()]*` Match any of the operators and match any char except `()`
  - `(?>` Atomic group

    - `[^()]+` Match 1+ times any char except `()`
    - `|` Or
    - `(?<o>)\(` Add to stack
    - `|` Or
    - `(?<-o>)\)` Remove from stack
  - `)*` Close atomic group and repeat 0+ times
  - `(?(o)(?!)|)\)` [Conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/alternation-constructs-in-regular-expressions#Conditional_Expr) with capturing group, evaluate the final subpattern
  - `|` Or
  - `\w+\|\w+\s*[<>!=]{1,2}\S+` Match 2 words divided by a pipe and match operators
- `)` Close non capture group

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5c%28%5cw%2b%5c%7c%5cw%2b%5cs*%5b%3c%3e%2b-%3d%5d%3d%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%28%3f%3e%5b%5e%28%29%5d%2b%7c%28%3f%3co%3e%29%5c%28%7c%28%3f%3c-o%3e%29%5c%29%29*%28%3f%28o%29%28%3f!%29%7c%29%5c%29%7c%5cw%2b%5c%7c%5cw%2b%5cs*%5b%3c%3e%2b-%3d%5d%3d%5cS%2b%29&i=%28%28Gripper%7cOpen%3d%3dtrue+OR+RIT%7cTurning%3d%3dfalse%29+AND+Robot%7cPosX+%3e%3d3+OR+%28Test%7cClose%3d%3dfalse+OR+%28Gripper%7cOpen%3d%3dfalse+AND+RIT%7cTurning%3d%3dfalse%29%29%29%0d%0a)

Comment: wow, impressive! only one thing, which you couldnt know: "[<>+-=]=" becomes "[<>!=]{1,2}" ( basically any c# compare operator )

Comment: do you know why                                                             Regex Conditions = new Regex(@"(?:\(\w+\s*\|\s*\w+\s*[<>!=]{1,2}\s*\w+[^()]*(?>[^()]+|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*(?(o)(?!)|)\)|\w+\s*\|\s*\w+\s*[<>!=]{1,2}\s*\w+)");
            var matches = Conditions.Matches(condition);
            return matches.Select(m => m.Value).ToList();   does find 4 results, while REGEX STORM only finds three?

Comment: actually, never mind... the were some more possible white spaces. The new complete regex is (?:\(\s*\w+\s*\|\s*\w+\s*[<>!=]{1,2}\s*\w+\s*[^()]*(?>[^()]+|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*(?(o)(?!)|)\)|\s*\w+\s*\|\s*\w+\s*[<>!=]{1,2}\s*\w+\s*)

Answer (score 1):

You may try with that:

```
(?<=\))(?!\()[^()]+|\((?!\()[^)]+\)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TryVck/1/)

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=\))(?!\()[^()]+ OR \((?!\()[^)]+\)
```

The first part before 'OR' basically matches **AND Robot|PosX >=3 OR**

1. `(?<=\))` negative lookbehind: match current character if the
   previous character is not )
2. `(?!\()` negative lookahead : match current character if the next
   charcter is not ( or )
3. `[^()]+` matches anything that is Neither ( nor ).

The last part after OR matches anything that starts with `(` and ends with `)` while ignoring any opening braces inside it.

Comment: works fine as well, however, i like the other answer a bit more, beacause of the precise two words devided by "|" pattern excluding the (AND/OR/XOR) boolean operators

Comment: I appreciate your choice, but operational cost / run time is more than double for the accepted solution

Comment: Yeah, that might be, but since I do it only once on initialization it does not really matter. Thanks anyways.